# CollapsingToolbarLayout with TablLayout not expanding or showing tabs

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to add a CollapsingToolbar to my existing activity which contains a TabLayout within a custom FrameLayout. From what I tried below, the toolbar is not fully expanded when scrolled to the top and instead disappears. The TabLayout also does not appear anywhere.

Here's what I have:

```
<org.corey.android.common_ui.CustomFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                               xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                               tools:context=".TestActivity"
                                               tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/test_tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    />


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/test_content_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button_container"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/test_activity_bottom_button_height"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/green_success"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@id/bottom_button_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_button_height"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/backgroundDark"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    style="@style/Dark.Button.Primary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                style="@style/progress_bar_standard"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</org.corey.android.common_ui.CustomFrameLayout>
```

I am trying to achieve something like this: https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea

Comment: Since you have a perfectly good working example, why don't you start with that and slowly make your changes to figure out what is breaking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **match_parent** here

```
<org.corey.android.common_ui.CustomFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                               xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                               tools:context=".TestActivity"
                                               tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
```

Then use  **app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"** for your Relative layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/test_content_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior
            android:background="@color/white">
```

3: use gravity if you want to put your tabs below toolbar

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/test_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                />
```